# jquery error - could not find what is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Firebug** console says

> phone is not defined

```
var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&phone=' + phone + '&email=' + email ;
```

error in this line

```
var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&phone=' + phone + '&email=' + email ;
```

If i swap phone with email then it shows email not defined, but i have input tag for all those fields.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We can't help without seeing some JS and/or HTML.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/magicaj/n5XUh/

Comment: Where are you getting your phone and email variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

in jQuery

```
var name = $("#name");;
var phone = $("#phone");
var email = $("#email");

var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&phone=' + phone + '&email=' + email ;
```

Plain Old JavaScript

```
var name = document.getElementById("name");;
var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
var email = document.getElementById("email");

var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&phone=' + phone + '&email=' + email ;
```

And Please make sure your input types haves the ids `name`,`phone` and `email`

**P.S : Just having input types wont have them magically associate themselves with variables with the same name in js**

Comment: yeah i have the id and the validation also works properly but the console always shows this error

Answer (score 0):

> but i have input tag for all those
>   fields.

name, phone and email have to JS variable and not just input tags. Make sure all of them are JS variables and in scope.